# TPM 2.0 hardware error DA lockout mode

Tags: tpm

I'm getting same error as mentioned in this post:
[TPM 2.0 simulator error DA lockout mode](https://superuser.com/questions/1391801/tpm-2-0-simulator-error-da-lockout-mode)
but with a discrete hardware tpm 2.0 module instead of simulator.

Tried clearing ownership:

```
# tpm2_takeownership -c -L lockpass
ERROR: Clearing Failed! TPM error code: 0x921
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_takeownership
```

Tried clearing dictionary lockout:

```
# tpm2_dictionarylockout -c -P lockpass
ERROR: 0x921 Error clearing dictionary lockout.
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_dictionarylockout
```

Neither works.

The error id decode says:

```
linux-hf35:~ # tpm2_rc_decode 0x921
error layer
  hex: 0x0
  identifier: TSS2_TPM_RC_LAYER
  description: Error produced by the TPM
format 0 warning code
  hex: 0x21
  name: TPM2_RC_LOCKOUT
  description: authorizations for objects subject to DA protection are not allowed at this time because the TPM is in DA lockout mode
```

Can't figure out how to get out of this lockout state. Has someone came across same error before? How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to switching off the tpm without  sending the `TPM_SHUTDOWN` command beforehand.

The following counter values may give you a better picture:

```
tpm2 getcap properties-variable | grep TPM2_PT_MAX_AUTH_FAIL
tpm2 getcap properties-variable | grep TPM2_PT_LOCKOUT_INTERVAL
tpm2 getcap properties-variable | grep TPM2_PT_LOCKOUT_RECOVERY
```

You can reset the lockout counter for `TPM_PT_MAX_AUTH_FAIL` using the following (setting `--max-tries` to the highest possible value means you will probably not see the problem again):

```
tpm2_dictionarylockout --setup-parameters --max-tries=4294967295 --clear-lockout
```